# How make a growth baby chart with data in mysql +PDO

Tags: mysql, charts, pdo, google-visualization

I am trying to make a chart with growth baby table I have in DB... I lost the idea and right now I don't know how to do it...[image: The chart I need to show]  this is the chart I need to show when the doctor insert the height and weight of every child...need to show the inserted the percentiles data and that will depend of the height and weight of the baby  to show the graph (gray line)...

here is my code until now ***(EDITED WITH NEW CODE)***:

```
<?php
include 'includes/configs.php';
/*
 * $normal is an array of (edad => peso) key/value pairs
 * $desnutricion is an array of (edad => peso) key/value pairs
 * $desnutricionSevera is an array of (edad => peso) key/value pairs
 * 
 * you can hard-code these or pull them from a database, whatever works for you
 */
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM ESTATURA WHERE edad<>'' AND peso<>'' AND id_paciente = 1");
$sql->execute();
$data = array(array('Meses', $apellido, 'Normal', 'Desnutricion', 'Desnutricion Severa'));
while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))  {
    $edad = $row['edad'];
    // use (int) to parse the value as an integer
    // or (float) to parse the value as a floating point number
    // use whichever is appropriate
    $edad = (int) preg_replace('/\D/', '', $edad);
    $peso = $row['peso'];
    $peso = (float) preg_replace('/\D/', '', $peso);

    $data[] = array($peso, $edad, $normal[$edad], $desnutricion[$edad], $desnutricionSevera[$edad]);
$data1[] = array($peso, $edad);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([<?php echo json_encode($data); ?>]);
            // sort the data by "Meses" to make sure it is in the right order
            data.sort(0);

            var options = {
                title: 'Grafica de Crecimiento de niÃ±as de 0 a 24 meses',
                hAxis: {
                    title: 'Meses',
                    titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}
                },
                vAxis: {
                    minValue: 0
                },
                series: {
                    0: {
                        <?php echo implode(",", $peso); ?>
                        type: 'line'
                    },
                    1: {
                        // series options for normal weight
                        type: 'area'
                    },
                    2: {
                        // series options for desnutricion
                        type: 'area'
                    },
                    3: {
                        // series options for desnutricion severa
                        type: 'area'
                    }
                }
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 800px; height: 400px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't understand how can insert the default variables (normal, desnutricion and desnutricion severa) with the baby variable.. I need to create a new table with the defaults data and then make a union? or just insert the variables in every series??

***--OLD CODE--***

```
<?php
include 'includes/configs.php';

$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT nombre, apellido, edad, peso FROM ESTATURA WHERE edad<>'' AND peso<>'' ");
$sql->execute();
while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))  {    
    $nombre = trim(addslashes($row['nombre']));
    $lapellido = trim(addslashes($row['apellido']));
    $edad = $row['edad'];
    $edad = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $edad);
    $peso = $row['peso'];
    $peso  = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $peso);

    $myurl[] = "['".$nombre." ".$apellido."', ".$edad.",".$peso."]";


    }    

    print_r($myurl);
    echo implode(",", $myurl);
?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Meses', 'Normal', 'DesnutriciÃ³n', 'DesnutriciÃ³n Severa'],
          /*['0',  4.23,      2.39,      2.00],
          ['1',  5.55,      3.10,      2.85],
          ['2',  6.75,      3.95,      3.41],
          ['3',  7.60,      4.50,      4.00],
          ['4',  8.23,      5.00,      4.40],
          ['5',  8.81,      5.38,      4.80],
          ['6',  9.30,      5.71,      5.11],
          ['7',  9.87,      6.00,      5.38],
          ['8',  10.19,      6.21,      5.58],
          ['9',  10.56,      6.47,      5.76],
          ['10',  10.95,      6.66,      5.95],
          ['11',  11.20,      6.80,      6.10],
          ['12',  11.55,      7.00,      6.21],
          ['13',  11.91,      7.20,      6.40],
          ['14',  12.10,      7.38,      6.58],
          ['15',  12.37,      7.54,      6.77],
          ['16',  12.60,      7.75,      6.85],
          ['17',  12.96,      7.86,      7.00],
          ['18',  13.16,      8.05,      7.20],
          ['19',  13.41,      8.20,      7.31],
          ['20',  13.72,      8.38,      7.42],
          ['21',  14.02,      8.49,      7.61],
          ['22',  14.24,      8.70,      7.79],
          ['23',  14.68,      8.90,      7.95],
          ['24',  14.90,      9.00,      8.00]*/
            <?php echo implode(",", $myurl); ?>
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Grafica de Crecimiento de niÃ±as de 0 a 24 meses',
          hAxis: {title: 'Meses',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
          vAxis: {minValue: 0}
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>

<div id="chart_div" style="width: 800px; height: 400px;"></div>
```

inside of `/*.....*/` is the percentiles that I need to show with the data in mysql...but I comented because the chart is not shown when that data don't have `/*...*/`

here the chart right now..[image]

can you help me with my type of chart?

Best Regards

Andrés Valencia

Comment: If I understand correctly, your database contains baby names (`nombre`, `apellido`), age (`edad`), and weight (`pesos`), and you want to chart age vs weight, right?  Is this age vs weight for a single baby or for a group of babies?  Where are you getting `Normal`, `Desnutricion`, and `Desnutricion Severa` from?

Comment: yes, the table ESTATURA have nombre, apellido, edad, peso and I need to chart height vs weight for single baby, because each baby have his/her id... so when the data of baby with per example id=1 is inserted (height, weight) in every prescription the chart will show all his/her history and need to show the normal, desnutricion, desnutricion severa to compares how the baby is growth...

Comment: Is this a problem related to MySQL itself (meaning: you cannot select the proper data), or to visualizing the data you've selected properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the basic framework you will need to make this work:

```
/*
 * $normal is an array of (edad => peso) key/value pairs
 * $desnutricion is an array of (edad => peso) key/value pairs
 * $desnutricionSevera is an array of (edad => peso) key/value pairs
 * 
 * you can hard-code these or pull them from a database, whatever works for you
 */
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT edad, peso FROM ESTATURA WHERE <criteria to select baby>");
$sql->execute();
$data = array(array('Meses', $apellido, 'Normal', 'Desnutricion', 'Desnutricion Severa'));
while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))  {
    $edad = $row['edad'];
    // use (int) to parse the value as an integer
    // or (float) to parse the value as a floating point number
    // use whichever is appropriate
    $edad = (int) preg_replace('/\D/', '', $edad);
    $peso = $row['peso'];
    $peso = (float) $peso;

    $data[] = array($edad, $peso, $normal[$edad], $desnutricion[$edad], $desnutricionSevera[$edad]);
}
```

Then, in your javascript:

```
function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<?php echo json_encode($data); ?>);
    // sort the data by "Meses" to make sure it is in the right order
    data.sort(0);

    var options = {
        title: 'Grafica de Crecimiento de niÃ±as de 0 a 24 meses',
        hAxis: {
            title: 'Meses',
            titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}
        },
        vAxis: {
            minValue: 0
        },
        series: {
            0: {
                // series options for this babys weight
                type: 'line'
            },
            1: {
                // series options for normal weight
                type: 'area'
            },
            2: {
                // series options for desnutricion
                type: 'area'
            },
            3: {
                // series options for desnutricion severa
                type: 'area'
            }
        }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Give that a try and see if it works for you.

Comment: I will try your code! but in this part= `// series options for desnutricion severa` I need to put something like this? = `<?php echo json_encode($desnutricionSevera); ?>`  ....  and for last in this part = `$data = array(array('Meses', $apellido, 'Normal', 'Desnutricion', 'Desnutricion Severa'));` the `$apellido` is for?

Comment: No, you don't want to put `<?php echo json_encode($desnutricionSevera); ?>` in the series option.  I used `$apellido` as a placeholder in the array of column names - you can call that column whatever you want.

Comment: can you show me a example for this? I tried but always show me nothing in the chart...

Comment: Open the page in a browser, view the source, and post the javascript.  I'll check it out and see if I can figure out what might be the problem.

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token { [graficas.php:31] <br/> that error is here:            0: {
                <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  implode() [<a href='function.implode'>function.implode</a>]: Invalid arguments passed in <b>/home/------/public_html/DEMOS/graficas.php</b> on line <b>57</b><br />
                type: 'line'
            },<br/> I insert this line: <?php echo implode(",", $peso); ?>

Comment: `<?php
include 'includes/configs.php';
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM ESTATURA WHERE edad<>'' AND peso<>'' AND id_paciente = 1");
$sql->execute();
$data = array(array('Meses', $apellido, 'Normal', 'Desnutricion', 'Desnutricion Severa'));
while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $edad = $row['edad'];
    $edad = (int) preg_replace('/\D/', '', $edad);
    $peso = $row['peso'];
    $peso = (float) preg_replace('/\D/', '', $peso);
    $data[] = array($peso, $edad, $normal[$edad], $desnutricion[$edad], $desnutricionSevera[$edad]);
$data1[] = array($peso, $edad);
}
?>`

Comment: The error you posted said something about an `implode` call, which isn't in the code you posted (or in the code I posted), so it's being caused by something else.

Comment: I thing is for this part:  `<?php echo implode(",", $peso); ?>` I used inside of : 0: {  <?php echo implode(",", $peso); ?>   type: 'line' },     1: .....

Comment: If `$peso` is the same variable used in the loop in the code I posted, then it isn't an array. and so you can't implode it.  It would help if you could update your original post with the new code so I can see how you are integrating everything together.

Comment: Hi, Asgallant I already update the code, hope that you find the problem.. I dont know right now how can I integrate the default variables(normal, desnutricion and desnutricion severa) with the variable saved for the medical in the prescription of each baby...Need I make another table with the default data and then make a union or just paste that data?

Comment: Why are you using the line `<?php echo implode(",", $peso); ?>` in the series option?  First, you can't implode `$peso` since it isn't an array, and second, there is no reason to have anything related to the contents of `$peso` in the series option.

Comment: well if I delete `<?php echo implode(",", $peso); ?>` the chart said me this: Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string

Comment: Open the page in a browser, view the source, and update you post with the javascript that is output on the line `var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([<?php echo json_encode($data); ?>]);`.  I'm looking to see what `json_encode($data)` is outputting here.

Comment: `var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([[["Meses",null,"Normal","Desnutricion","Desnutricion Severa"],[1278,8,null,null,null],[745,4,null,null,null]]]);` this is the output.

Comment: Ok, I see the problem.  You have an extra pair of brackets in the `arrayToDataTable` call (my mistake, I didn't take them out when I copied your code - I'll fix in my answer above).  The line should be: `var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<?php echo json_encode($data); ?>);`

Comment: now said me this: `All series on a given axis must be of the same data type`

Comment: The `arrayToDataTable` method uses the first row of data to detect the data types of each column, so with null values, the data type is not found, and thus you get that error.  The way around this is to switch to the regular `DataTable` constructor; you can either define the columns manually in javascript or you can convert your PHP to create a JSON representation of a DataTable (this is not much more complicated than what you are already doing).

Comment: Thank you asgallant!, your support is great... one more question: Can I call the default variables(the data for normal, desnutricion and desnutricion severa) with a mysql union (because I thing make another table with those data) or just call in another mysql select or is better in javascript call?

Comment: another thing... right now the chart show data but in values with "decimals" show me diferent values... per example if I have 12.78 in chart show me 1278...how can I change that to show me the values with decimals like 7.15, 12.78, etc..

Comment: You don't want to use a `UNION` in your SQL - a `JOIN` is what you want if you have the other values in another table.  I think the problem with your decimals is being caused by `preg_replace('/\D/', '', $peso);`, which is stripping all non-numeric characters from the `$peso` string - including the decimal separator.  What do the raw string values of `$peso` look like?

Comment: the output show these: `[1278,8,null,null,null],[745,4,null,null,null]` and I need to show in this form: `[12.78,8,null,null,null],[7.45,4,null,null,null]` because in the table is save it in this form: peso 7.45 (this is in kg.) varchar with 6,2 decimal

Comment: Is the string in the database literally "peso 7.45" or is it "7.45"?

Comment: is just "7.45"  or "12.78"

Comment: Ok.  Change the line `$peso = (float) preg_replace('/\D/', '', $peso);` to `$peso = (float) $peso;` - I will update my answer.

Comment: Thank you Asgallant! Now show me the data like I need it.  GREAT support! Best Regards!

Comment: I follow your tip in this [http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/MEtbm/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/MEtbm/1/) for join tables..but not have success...have you a link where I can join two tables with mysql data?

Comment: I have this code: `...
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM ESTATURA ; SELECT * FROM ESTATURABB WHERE id_paciente = 1");
...
$data = array(array('Meses', 'Normal', 'Desnutricion', 'Desnutricion Severa' , $id_b));
while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))  { $edad = $row['edad']; $edad = (int) preg_replace('/\D/', '', $edad); $peso1 = $row['peso1']; $peso1 = (float) $peso1; $peso2 = $row['peso2']; $peso2 = (float) $peso2; $peso3 = $row['peso3']; $peso3 = (float) $peso3; $peso = $row['peso'];  $peso = (float) $peso; $data[] = array($edad, $peso1, $peso2, $peso3, $peso);
}`

Comment: the chart showed but no info in the line peso.(sorry for make two comments)

Comment: What table contains your comparison data (`Desnutricion` and `Desnutricion Severa`)?

Comment: I have two tables the first one is ESTATURA with these rows: id_bb, edad, peso1(normal), peso2(desnutricion) and peso3(desnutricion severa). this table have the default percentiles(weight and height) since 0 to 24 month and the second table is ESTATURABB with these rows: id_b, edad, peso and id_paciente(this table will save the patient data every month).   Right now the chart show the ESTATURA table and the SECOND table ESTATURABB but not show the demo value I inserted for demo.. show the line but with 0 values

Comment: You will want a SQL query with something like this: `SELECT a.edad, b.peso, a.\`peso(desnutricion)\`, a.\`peso(desnutricion severa)\` FROM estatura as a LEFT JOIN estaturabb as b ON a.edad = b.edad WHERE b.id_paciente = ?`

Comment: my friend..I don't know how can I paid you for all your great support!  ... you help me a lot, this is my first chart and if not for you I never could have done this.  best regards!

Comment: Hi @asgallant I followed this chart and works very nice, but I need to know how can make to update the chart  or refresh if one data is saved into DB without refresh entire the page, just refresh the chart...maybe with a button?