# Hide and show different divs depending of data in row

Tags: php, jquery, show-hide

How can I **hide** per example **girl chart** if the gender of user is male or viceversa?

I saw different questions here but I don't see something like I need... this can do it?..

I thing is something like these:

```
    <?php if($user->getRole() == 'Mod'|| $user->isAdmin()) { ?>
<div id="girlchart" style="width: 450px; height: 300px;"></div>
    <?php } ?>
```

or

```
    <?php if (!empty($row["gender"])) { ?>
<div id="boychart" style="width: 450px; height: 300px;"></div>
    <?php } ?>
```

but I can't figure how to do it...

--EDIT(sorry for my english...I can't explain me better.)--

I have two charts one for baby girl of 0 to 24 month  and another for baby boy of 0 to 24 month... so I need to hide one of them if the patient is boy or viceversa(girl), I need hide to see only the growth chart of that baby(gender) and don't have two charts.

can you help me?

---

**--EDIT 2---**

I have a DB (paciente) with these rows:

- id
- name
- gender ----this row identify the user if is girl or boy(male or female)
- status
- birthday

now I have a charts for growth see hte link: [growth chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19190205/how-make-a-growth-baby-chart-with-data-in-mysql-pdo) here Asgallant give me a great support to make it works the charts so went the **medic** see the data of patient with id per example 1 to give the prescription he save in DB ESTATURA (see the link above) the weight(peso) and age(edad) for see how the baby have growing... until here is all ok.

in each chart addition of patient data there are the default values (normal, desnutricion and desnutricion severa) and every values are different in boy or girl so I have in the perfil of every patient the charts *growth baby chart for boy* and *growth baby chart for girl* but I need only show one of them...this is my question
:
How can I show only one chart? if the patient is boy show the growth baby chart for boy or if the patient is girl only show the growth baby chart for girl..

To make this I think is for the gender(row in DB paciente) because here identify the patient in male or female because that I put that code(see in the code in above) but I don't know how implement it in good format.

Comment: I can't figure it out either, what you are asking !

Comment: sorry, I added more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with just simple way:

```
<?php
//ur query something like this, u change it according to ur need
$query = "SELECT id,name,gender,status,birthday FROM ur_table_name";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    if($row['gender'] == "male") //here ur condition to check for male
    {
        $girldiv = "display:none";
    }
    else ////here ur condition to check for female
    {
        $boydiv = "display:none";
    }   
}
?>

<div id="girlchart" style="width: 450px; height: 300px; <?php echo $girldiv; ?>">

</div>

<div id="boychart" style="width: 450px; height: 300px; <?php echo $boydiv; ?>">

</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Ashish , yes I think is something like this...but the condition is that I don't know how to do it..

Comment: @Andrés : look i hav edited answer but u give conditions according to ur query structure..

Comment: thank you my friend! that is the code I was looking for. Best regards!

Comment: Hi @Ashish if I need hide divs per age? like per example show info about XX if the user have 0 to 2 years and another div only if the user have for 2 to 5 years..

Comment: @asterix_jv yes u can do it..in similar way u can give condition for age..

Comment: Hi Ashish,  I tried something like this but dont hide nothing:  
`<?php  $sql = $conn->prepare("select edad from vacunas where id_user = $id_user"); $sql->execute(); while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ if($row['edad'] >0 && $row['edad'] <=24) { $bebediv = "display:none"; } else if($row['edad'] >24 && $row['edad'] <=60) { $ninodiv = "display:none"; }    }  ?>` and inside of div this code: `<div style="<?php echo $bebediv; ?>">`... can you help me with this, Best Regards

Comment: <div style=" <?php echo $bebediv; ?>"> try this..its working fine @ my place..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<html lang="en-US" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
    <head>
        <title>Test page</title>

        <script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(":radio:eq(0)").click(function(){
                    $("#div_boy").show(1000);
                    $("#div_girl").hide(1000);
                });

                $(":radio:eq(1)").click(function(){
                    $("#div_girl").show(1000);
                    $("#div_boy").hide(1000);
                });

            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="radio" name="lang_anz" value="1"> Boyz<br>
        <input type="radio" name="lang_anz" value="0"> Girlz<br>
        <div id="div_boy" style="display: none">Boys Information.</div>
        <div id="div_girl" style="display: none">Girls Information.</div>
    </body>
```

Note: Please add jquery file for running the javascript code.

Thanks